# Name for a special type of abbreviation, such as "mart" for "market"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Is there a name for when an abbreviation deviates greatly from the main word, as "mart" does for "market"?

Comment: Who knows why and how words are shortened?  Bill Franke is on the right track regarding the word "mart," but as for other words, perhaps the reason they are shortened is attributable to sheer laziness!  Is it that much easier to say lit than literature?  How about porn for pornographic, or memo for memorandum, or sub for substitute (teacher), or per for pursuant to, or--well, you get the idea.  For many, if not most, of truncated words, I have a feeling there are a myriad  reasons for their truncation.

Comment: How is that a "great deviation"? It's more like a contraction; the first three letters are butted against the last letter; same as _dept_ for _department_ and _reqt_  for _requirement_.

Comment: The presumptions of *mart* as an "abbreviation" of *market* and of its "deviation" appear preposterous. NARQ.

Answer (score 2):

"[Mart](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=mart&searchmode=none)" is a word coined in the middle of the 1400s. The abbreviation for "market" is "[mkt](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mkt)". If it was borrowed from Middle Dutch "markt", the **orthographic shortening** is understandable: English phonetics doesn't provide for the sound represented by *kt* in Dutch.

It seems to me to be merely a **respelling**, just as American English has changed British English spellings of words like "foetus" to "fetus", "haematology" to "hematology", and "colour" to "color", and, for example, the German spelling of *München* to *Munich*.

Comment: It should perhaps be noted a little more strongly that *mart* is not an abbreviation of *market* but a different word, although the two have a common origin in Latin *mercari, mercatus*, 'trade'. According to [*OED*](http://archive.org/stream/oed6barch#page/188/mode/2up), sv **Mart**,*sb.* 4, *mart* was borrowed from Dutch at a time when it was often spelled (and presumably pronounced) <mart> **in that language**. Originally it was used specifically of the markets of the Low Countries, not being generalized until the end of the 16th century.